# Displaying an image from an API In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display the image of the breed selected by the user in this code but it is not working,

any ideas or hints as of why?

Thank you

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './breed-image.css';

function BreedImage () {
    const [breed, selectedBreed] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchImage();
        }, []);

    const fetchImage = async () => {
        const res = await fetch(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${breed}/images/random`)
        const data = await res.json();
        const imageUrl = data.message
        selectedBreed(imageUrl);
        };

    return (
      <div className="image-container">
        <img className="image-card" src={breed} alt="doggopicture" />
      </div>
    );
  
}

export default BreedImage;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's some weird logic in here that doesn't make sense.  `breed` is initialized to an empty string.  Then, in your useEffect you have an empty dependencies array, which means it will be called once.  Which means your API request hits `https://dog.ceo/api/breed//images/random` which presumably would fail (since breed was `''`).

Most likely you instead want:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './breed-image.css';

function BreedImage () {
    const [breed, setBreed] = useState('');
    const [url, setUrl] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchImage();
    }, [breed]);

    const fetchImage = async () => {
        const res = await fetch(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${breed}/images/random`)
        const data = await res.json();
        setUrl(data.message);
    };

    return (
    <>
      <DogPicker onChange={(breed) => setBreed(breed)} />
      <div className="image-container">
        <img className="image-card" src={url} alt="doggopicture" />
      </div>
    </>
    );
  
}

export default BreedImage;
```

where you'd pass `setBreed` to some other component.  Or, you could pass `breed` down to this component as a prop, and again use `useEffect` to watch for changes.